# OutOfMemoryError from reading a text file

Tags: java, groovy

I need to parse a csv file at work. Each line in the file is not very long, only a few hundred characters. I used the following code to read the file into memory.

```
def lines = []
new File( fileName ).eachLine { line -> lines.add( line ) }
```

When the number of lines is 10,000, the code works just fine. However, when I increase the number of lines to 100,000. I got this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

For 10,000 lines, the file size is about 7 MB, and ~70 MB for 100,000 lines. So, how would you solve this problem? I know increasing the heap size is a work-around. But are there any other solutions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could process each line instead of saving all the lines in memory, or for some reason you really need to have them in memory?

Comment: I am not familiar with groovy but is 'new File( fileName ).eachLine { line -> lines.add( line ) }' creating new object every time it reads a line from the csv file? I personally did the same stuff with python and never get any error.

Comment: You are adding every line to a list in memory. The list `lines` is getting fat and causing OOM

Comment: What are you doing with the lines array/list you define on line one?  What problem are you solving by having each line stored in an array?

Comment: @Brian: It is a CSV file. Each line contains multiple fields. Basically I need to break a line into those fields.

Comment: @JBT so you don't need all the lines in memory  You can process one line at a time, insert into database, move to next line.  Get rid of the lines.add() and just implement your logic in the closure that you want to perform with each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def lines = []
```

In groovy, this creates an `ArrayList<E>` with size 0 and no preallocation of the internal `Object[]`.

When adding items, if capacity is reached, a new `ArrayList` is created. The larger the list, the more time spent reallocating a new list to accommodate new entries. I suspect that's where your memory issue occurs because, although I'm not exactly sure how ArrayList allocates a new list, if you're getting OOM for a relatively small data set, that's where I'd look first. For 100,000 entries, you create a new list roughly 29 times ([assuming expansion factor of 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15430259/791406)) when starting with an empty `ArrayList`.

If you have a general idea how large the list needs to be, just set the initial capacity, doing so avoids all the reallocating nonsense; see if this works:

```
def lines = new ArrayList<String>(100000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are likely trying to place the CSV file in a database you can do something like this.  The key groovy feature is **splitEachLine(yourDelimiter)** and using the fields array in the closure.

```
import groovy.sql.*

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL",
    "scott", "tiger", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")

//define a variable that matches a table definition (jdbc dataset
def student = sql.dataSet("TEMP_DATA");
//now iterate over the csv file splitting each line on commas and load the into table.
new File("C:/temp/file.csv").splitEachLine(","){ fields ->
//insert each column we have into the temp table.
 student.add(
        STUDENT_ID:fields[0],
        FIRST_NAME:fields[1],
        LAST_NAME:fields[2]
    )
}
//yes the magic has happened the data is now in the staging table TEMP_DATA.
println "Number of Records  " + sql.firstRow("Select count(*) from TEMP_DATA")
```