# What is the best practice for setting the initial capacity of an ArrayList that is not always used?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, capacity

I have some classes that have `ArrayList` fields that are only sometimes used. I generally initialize these fields like so:

```
private List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
```

I understand about [using the overload constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity) to set the initial capacity, so I'm wondering if I should declare these fields as such:

```
private List<Widget> widgets = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

The dilemma, is that if I initialize the list with 0 then the list will *always* have to re-initialize itself for adding even one item. But, if I use the default constructor, which gives a default capacity of 10, then I may have a bunch of items (and there can be many) that are wasting memory with unused capacity.

I know some of you are going to push back asking 'how often' and 'how many items are you expecting' but **I'm really looking for the "best practices" approach. All things being ~equal, should one initialize with `(0)` or `()` on a list that is sometimes used?**

It's our department policy to *always* initialize lists, so I may not simply leave the lists as `null`, besides, that would just side-step the question.

Comment: This is micro-optimization. Use the default no-arg constructor unless you know you have an issue here.

Comment: You really have a policy how to handle List initialization? Amazing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Premature optimisation is the root of all evil. - D. Knuth.

This seems like the kind of "performance issue" which actually never has any effect on performance. For one thing, how sure are you that these empty lists are actually initialised? I suspect that most modern compilers delay initialisation of objects until they know for sure that there will be a call on them. So if you pass the no arg constructor it will most likely never be used unless something is added to the list. On the other hand, if you use the 0 argument constructor, it guarantees that it has to resize every one that it uses.

These are the three laws of performance optimisation

1. Never assume that you know what the compiled code is actually doing, or that you can sport small optimisations better than the compiler can.
2. Never optimise without using a profiler to work out where the bottleneck is. If you think that you know, refer to rule number (1).
3. Don't bother unless your application has a performance issue. Then refer to rule (2).

On the off chance that you somehow still believe that you understand compilers, check out this question: [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: @hil_20686 generally, this *is right*. But *sanity and generally* does not create super fast code. LMAX for example...

Comment: Optimising Java is seriously hard. You have no control of memory allocation, little or no control of the compiler, and the fact that it compiles code on the fly gives you serious overheads on seldom used branches.

Obviously that is not to say good code is not faster than bad code, but this kind of micro optimisation just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is not always used use lazy initialization

```
private List<Widget> widgets;

private List<Widget> getList() {
    if (widgets == null) {
         widgets = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return widgets;
}
```

Comment: Would *you* actually do this for a list? You've written more code for zero noticeable benefit. More code is more bugs (or at least more code for bugs to hide in) and more do-nothing code to maintain and skip over while reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you set it to 0 the `ArrayList` will have to resize anyhow, so really you're shooting yourself in the foot. The only time you would benefit from an explicit declaration of size would be if you already know the maximum bounds that you will be reaching in your list.

As stated, this is a micro-optimization, it's more likely you will find other things that you can significantly improve than the initial size of your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

I tent to disagree that these optimisation are *bad*. If you declare an arraylist that holds n elements (8-th by default if Im not mistaken), and you put one more, then arraylist, internally will double the size it holds. When you remove this element later, the list *will not decrease*.

Comment: They are bad! Good developer shouldn't be wasting their time on micro-optimizations, unless it's Linux core or something like that. It's counterproductive.

Comment: @DenisKulagin :) not even going to comment.

Comment: Don't mean to start a holy war. Because it would be counterproductive too!

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList utilizes processor cache a lot and actually is so fast, that you don't need to optimize it any furter. Still, if you have to create millions of tiny ArrayList instances it may worth thinking of reworking your overall design and not bother about default AL capacity.

Comment: @enisKulagin *everything* (every code you write) uses cpu cache.

Comment: ArrayList squeeze the most of it. If you benchmark it, ArrayList wins a competition with LinkedList even for insertion operation!

Comment: this has nothing to do with cpu cache. Of course arraylist is going to be faster at insert then linkedlist.

Comment: @Eugene Why? From pure DS&A theory linked list should win, because in theory insertion operation is O(1) for linked list.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been said, Lazy initialization can help you by postponing the moment when you have to initialize the list (and therefore choose its initial size).

If Lazy initialization is not possible because of your department policy that does not allow to initialize with null an object (for which I do not find much sense), a workaround might be to initialize an empty list as

`List widget = new ArrayList<>(0)`

and only when (and if) you actually need to work with the list, you create a new list object:

`widget = new ArrayList<>(someSize)`

and hopefully at that moment you could know the max size that the list can reach (or at least its order of magnitude).

I know, this is a very stupid trick, but it adhers to your policy.