# Why ArrayList has no varargs constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, constructor

My question may sound silly, but please, read the whole question first.

I wonder for a long time, why `ArrayList` and other classes implementing List, Set etc., doesn't provide a simple constructor accepting the variable count of parameters?

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(1, 2, 3);
```

This looks simple and obvious. Java 9 provides newly `List.of()` static factory method which only copies the same what Apache Utils and Guava have introduced. We are forced to use the verbose workarounds.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ add(1); add(2); add(3); }};
```

...unless we are happy to upgrade to Java 9 or add a dependency to one of the util libraries above or create a class extending `ArrayList` and writing our own constructor.

---

Finally, the question I ask: **What reason made designers omit this constructor?**

You can argue me that there already exists a constructor [ArrayList(int initialCapacity)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) which "constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity" (source at the same page) - I am aware this conflicts my idea, but honestly: how many times we had to declare the size of ArrayList in advance? Don't we need an ArrayList with predefined values used for ex. unit tests data? Isn't enough to initialize `new ArrayList<>()` which calls `this(10)` by default for 99,9% of cases?

Each `List::add(..)` calls a method that ensures the size of the array storing the values which are expensive for the huge amount of data and the constructor of ArrayList with a predefined size is welcome - so, why don't we use an array? Do we need to edit the large array afterward? - add it to the ArrayList using Arrays.asList(array) which calls `System.arraycopy` just [once](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), or we can [ensureCapacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity-int-).

This is how I understand the current design of ArrayList after browsing through some of the classes in java.util. Please, correct me where my understanding is wrong or knowledge insufficient.

**Is there any technical issue explaining why constructor** `new ArrayList<>(1, 2, 3)` **was not realized?**

Comment: I don't see why the initial capacity parameter would conflict with a varargs initializer.

Comment: shmosel: new ArrayList<>(1), where 1 is int - would it be a size of the list or the first element?

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis:  It wouldn't conflict at all.  Java's smart enough to determine which parameter to use from that alone.

Comment: @Makoto I don't think it is.

Comment: @Makoto I can't even tell. How would Java know?

Comment: @Aominè It *would* conflict, and your suggestion proves it.

Comment: @EJP Right, true!

Comment: @Aominè:  [You're not forced at all.](https://repl.it/repls/DarkturquoiseBlueBetaversion)

Comment: It seems like you're actually asking why `initialCapacity` is necessary/useful, which is really a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity).

Comment: @Makoto my point is doing `new ArrayList<>(1)` would always pick the non varargs constructor overload which in this case would be constructing an ArrayList with a capacity rather than an ArrayList with a single element. so assuming the user of this API really wanted an ArrayList with a single element and there was a varargs overload then you're _forced_ to help the compiler pick the varargs version by using the array syntax.

Comment: Furthermore, `new ArrayList<>(1, 2)` would be considered ambiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ArrayList` existed in Java 1.2.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)  Varargs were a feature introduced [in Java 1.5](http://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs) (along with a whole heap of other features).

All of the features you really require from a vararg initialization of a list can be realized in [`Arrays.asList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/Arrays.java#3354), which had to have existed around or after Java 1.5 due to its use of varargs.

Comment: Arrays.asList pre-dates varargs, but the argument had type Object[].