# ArrayList public constructor - "Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten" - where?

Tags: java, arraylist

Be aware, it is **not** a duplicate of [Why start an ArrayList with an initial capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity)

Looking into the source code of the `java.util.ArrayList` class, starting from at least java 1.8 I see the following code:

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Where

```
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

Though the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--) officially states:

> Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

I outline: **...an initial capacity of ten**. Where is this *ten*?

Am I completely mad and missing something, or there is simply a javadoc bug here?

**UPD:** How it looked like prior java 1.8:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}

/**
 * Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.
 */
public ArrayList() {
    this(10);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an optimization. The developers decided to initialize the `ArrayList` with an empty backing array, and lazily create a non-empty backing array only when you start adding elements to the `List`.

When you add the first element (by calling `add`), it calls

```
ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);
```

which checks if `elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA`, and if so, sets the capacity to

```
minCapacity = Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);
```

`DEFAULT_CAPACITY` is `10`.

Comment: But I still don't get, it is explicitly said: *an initial capacity of ten*. Where is this *ten*? :p

Comment: @Andremoniy see edit

Comment: I see. It's a good catch. No doubts. HOWEVER. There is a big difference for those who only reads the javadoc: before java 1.8 it would make sense to create ```ArrayList(0)``` to make it a slightly more efficient, isn't it? So I would insist that this is a kind of bug in javadoc...

Comment: @Andremoniy I'm not sure it's a bug in javadoc. I'd call it an implementation detail.

Comment: Could you check please, where this `ensureCapacityInternal` is called? It seems to me that by calling just ```ArrayList::add``` it won't be enlarged to `10` elements...

Comment: @Andremoniy `add` calls `ensureCapacityInternal(1)` (when the list is empty), which calls `ensureExplicitCapacity(10)`, which calls `grow(10)`, which calls `elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);`

Comment: That's true, I've also checked. Thanks.

Comment: @Andremoniy I think this is not a documentation error because another implementation (based on OpenJDK) may decide to revert to the Java 7 way of initializing the capacity to 10, and still be compliant with the official documentation. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Oracle's Java API documentation does not just document the Oracle implementation, but all conforming JDKs).

Comment: It almost certainly is a "bug" in the JavaDocs. The JavaDocs are describing the situation before Java 8, and simply have not been updated. (One could certainly argue about the meaning of "initial capacity", but even if it means "initial capacity *after the first element was added*", it would still be confusing)

Answer (score 3):

The capacity will be set as 10 when you add element to the list first time.

See this:

```
/**
 * Default initial capacity.
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
```

**Complete procedure**

Step 1:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}
```

Step 2:

```
private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

Step 3, the list `grows`:

```
private Object[] grow() {
    return grow(size + 1); // size is 0 here
}

private Object[] grow(int minCapacity) {
    return elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData,
                                       newCapacity(minCapacity));  // newCapacity(1) will return 10, see step 4, the elementData will have capacity 10.
}
```

Step 4, call `newCapacity(1)`:

```
private int newCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity <= 0) {
        if (elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA)
            return Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity);   // will  return 10 here !!!!
        if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        return minCapacity;
    }
    return (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE <= 0)
        ? newCapacity
        : hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your detailed answer. Though it appears that my question is a duplicate.