# Java : Initialize the ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, arraylist

Which is best way to initialize the ArrayList If I know the size of element in advance.

**A)**

```
List<Map<String, Object>> docList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(size);
```

OR

**B)**

```
List<Map<String, Object>> docList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

What is the performance effect if I am using A or B.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity

Comment: Possible duplicates are [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430247/why-start-an-arraylist-with-an-initial-capacity) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172480/whats-meant-by-parameter-int-initial-capacity-in-an-arraylist)

Comment: duplicate; hence down voting it !