# What is the Default ArrayList size in Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, resize, size

1. What is the default size for an arraylist in java 8? As far as I remember and searched on google, everywhere I am finding that it is 10 by default but when I am taking output of the below code, it is printing 0. Is there any changes happened in java 8 related to this?

   ```
   ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
   System.out.println("size:"+arrList.size());
   ```
2. My second query is: when I add some element to the list, then will the size increase by 1.5 times of previous size or it will increase by only 1?

**PS:** Is there any way to know the current capacity of the arraylist object?

Comment: The **size** of an empty list is 0.

Comment: What you mean is 'capacity' not size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946920/distinction-between-the-capacity-of-an-array-list-and-the-size-of-an-array, also related are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172480/whats-meant-by-parameter-int-initial-capacity-in-an-arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial `List` has the `capacity` zero (unless you specify otherwise):

```
 private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

When it has to grow, this is used:

```
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)
```

`oldCapacity >> 1` is division by two, so it grows by **1.5**

The one thing to notice that once you remove elements, the capacity does not change. If you need it to shrink use `trimToSize`.

The `10` is right actually, but *only* when you put an element into the `ArrayList`:

```
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();

    Field f = ar.getClass().getDeclaredField("elementData");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    int l = ((Object[]) f.get(ar)).length;
    System.out.println(l); // 0

    ar.add("1");

    int x = ((Object[]) f.get(ar)).length;
    System.out.println(x); // 10
```

Comment: According to the Javadoc, the initial capacity is 10...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth indeed... but this code `Field f =arrayList.getClass().getDeclaredField("elementData");f.setAccessible(true);int l = ((Object[]) f.get(arrayList)).length;System.out.println(l);` would output a zero...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that's clever :) the 10 is deferred until you actually put something in the `ArrayList`. thx, I should have read that documentation.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a lazy implementation ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing size with capacity. Size is the number of elements you have placed into the `arrayList` while capacity is the max number of elements the `arrayList` can take. Once you've reached max, the capacity is doubled(if i remember correctly).

So when you add an element into your `arrayList`, size will always increase by one. If size is equal to capacity, then capacity will increase.